# Gulp を使って同じ階層にフォルダを新たに生成して保存したい

Tags: gulp

初めまして。フロントエンドエンジニア歴1ヶ月の超初心者です。中学生の時にHTMLとCSSを独学してから
まともに勉強したことはないくらい初心者です。Javascript は一切理解できません。
WEB制作を主にやっていくことになりましたが、周りのエンジニアは Gulp を使っていない職場です。
個人的に調べて、個人で吸収しています。

Gulp-rename で現在こんな指定をしています。

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('src/**/sass/**/*.scss')
            .pipe(plumber({
                    errorHandler: notify.onError('Error: <%= error.message %>')
            }))
            .pipe(frontnote())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass({
                    outputStyle: 'expanded',
                    sourcemap: true
            }))
            .pipe(autoprefixer({
                    browsers: ['last 2 version'],
                    cascade: false
            }))
            .pipe(mmq())
            .pipe(beautify({
                    indent: '   '
            }))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write(''))
            .pipe(rename(function(path) {
                    path.dirname += '/css';
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'))
            .pipe(browser.reload({
                    stream: true
            }))
            .pipe(cssmin())
            .pipe(rename({
                    suffix: '.min'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'))
});
```

階層がこんな感じ

```
src
 ├ Project1
 │    └ sass
 │       └ css ←ここに出力される
 ├ Project2
 ├ Project3
 │    ├ sass
 │    └ css ←ここに出力したい！
 ├ Project4
 │
 gulpfile.js
```

こんな感じになっているのですが、
sass と css の出力先を同じ階層にした異のですが、出来ずにいます。
どなたか、解決策ありましたら、教えていただきたいです…

皆さんは開発ディレクトリと
出力ディレクトリは分けているかもしれませんが
その時も sass のディレクトリ内に css フォルダが出来てしまうのをどう回避しているのか知りたいです。